# sudo chmod permission denied

Tags: command-line, chmod, permission-denied

I accidentally executed the following command:

sudo chmod -R 0700 /lib

Now every single command (even with sudo) gives me a 'permission denied' (even simple commands like 'ls'). I got told because all the important executable files in the lib folder are not executable anymore.

Basically my system is blocked. Is there a way to restore this (it is a server so reinstalling is not an option)?

Comment: Ouch. Hope you have a backup.

Comment: "actual dentily"??? I think I need a newer dictionary...